# heroku open does not work. Following twitter clone tutorial, ribbit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

My apologies for any obvious errors I am missing. I am relatively new to ruby and programming in general.

https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/building-ribbit-in-rails/lessons/creating-the-application-template

After typing 'heroku open' on command line I receive the error message:

The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

this is my heroku log -T

```
Emilios-MacBook-Pro:ribbit1 TheBabadook$ heroku logs -t
2016-09-28T03:36:49.149660+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2]
2016-09-28T03:36:49.148897+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] Started GET "/" for 104.162.114.18 at 2016-09-28 03:36:49 +0000
2016-09-28T03:36:49.149691+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2016-09-28T03:36:49.149757+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2]
2016-09-28T03:36:49.149789+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.149814+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.149844+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.149872+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.149988+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.149952+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150019+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.149899+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.149924+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150042+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150338+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150070+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150369+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150097+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150402+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150122+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150154+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150183+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150212+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150242+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150271+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
2016-09-28T03:36:49.150306+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a15eea8-9a4f-47ac-bba1-fef1391488f2] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.387907+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=calm-brushlands-63827.herokuapp.com request_id=3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771 fwd="104.162.114.18" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=1744
2016-09-28T03:41:48.372564+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] Started GET "/" for 104.162.114.18 at 2016-09-28 03:41:48 +0000
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373126+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771]
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373146+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373221+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373159+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771]
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373247+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373174+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373259+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373301+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373279+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373290+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373360+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373312+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373371+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373325+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373337+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373348+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373456+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373398+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373424+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373445+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373466+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373478+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373520+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373489+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
2016-09-28T03:41:48.373500+00:00 app[web.1]: [3c4a0f6c-6f0c-4f80-8bd7-df83c8e68771] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `call'
2016-09-28T04:16:34.669686+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2016-09-28T04:16:34.670436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-09-28T04:16:37.206037+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-09-28T04:16:37.902957+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2016-09-28T04:16:37.903216+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2016-09-28 04:16:37 +0000 ===
2016-09-28T04:16:37.903246+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2016-09-28T04:16:37.903457+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-09-28T04:16:38.084555+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-09-28T15:44:55.023011+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2016-09-28T15:44:55.023329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-09-28T15:44:57.262220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 6823 -e production`
2016-09-28T15:44:59.998022+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2016-09-28T15:44:59.998040+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:6823
2016-09-28T15:44:59.998041+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-09-28T15:45:00.857318+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-09-28T15:45:00.748363+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2016-09-28T15:45:00.748408+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.2.2-p95), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
2016-09-28T15:45:00.748409+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2016-09-28T15:45:00.748410+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2016-09-28T15:45:00.748502+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:6823
2016-09-28T15:45:00.748863+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2016-09-28T15:45:02.109026+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=calm-brushlands-63827.herokuapp.com request_id=4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7 fwd="104.162.114.18" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=39ms status=404 bytes=1744
2016-09-28T15:45:02.112273+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] Started GET "/" for 104.162.114.18 at 2016-09-28 15:45:02 +0000
2016-09-28T15:45:02.113665+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7]
2016-09-28T15:45:02.113717+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2016-09-28T15:45:02.113758+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7]
2016-09-28T15:45:02.113796+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.113833+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.113879+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.113932+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.113935+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.113971+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114079+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114004+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114114+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114161+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114195+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114230+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114267+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114297+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114337+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114371+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114403+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114428+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114454+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114486+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114529+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `call'
2016-09-28T15:45:02.114564+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ba96dd9-a2d7-4ea5-93f2-e74ba40674d7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

This is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end


gem 'rails_12factor'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

This is my gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.0.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)
      nio4r (~> 1.2)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.0.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)
      actionview (= 5.0.0.1)
      activejob (= 5.0.0.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.0.0.1)
      actionview (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
    activerecord (5.0.0.1)
      activemodel (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      arel (~> 7.0)
    activesupport (5.0.0.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (7.1.2)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (9.0.5)
    coffee-rails (4.2.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.2.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.14)
    globalid (0.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.6.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.2.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    listen (3.0.8)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.9.1)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    nio4r (1.2.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.8)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
      pkg-config (~> 1.1.7)
    pg (0.18.4)
    pkg-config (1.1.7)
    puma (3.6.0)
    rack (2.0.1)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (5.0.0.1)
      actioncable (= 5.0.0.1)
      actionmailer (= 5.0.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)
      actionview (= 5.0.0.1)
      activejob (= 5.0.0.1)
      activemodel (= 5.0.0.1)
      activerecord (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 5.0.0.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0, < 6.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (5.0.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.3.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
    rb-inotify (0.9.7)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    spring (1.7.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.0)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (~> 1.2)
    sprockets (3.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.11)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    turbolinks (5.0.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5)
    turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (3.3.1)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      debug_inspector
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.6.4)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  listen (~> 3.0.5)
  pg
  puma (~> 3.0)
  rails (~> 5.0.0, >= 5.0.0.1)
  rails_12factor
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  sqlite3
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.2.2p95

BUNDLED WITH
   1.13.1
```

I created a controller using rails generate controller Welcome index in hopes of 'heroku open' working

```
This is my routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'



  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

This is my welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController


  def index
  end
end
```

This is my index.html.erb

```
<h1>Welcome#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>
```

In production.rb I tried changing

```
'config.assets.compile = false'
to 'config.assets.compile = true' with no success.
```

I tried but it did not work.

```
$ heroku rake db:migrate
$ heroku run rake db:setup
```

Comment: Did you setup a root route in your config.routes file?

Comment: Yes. I added 'root 'welcome#index' to my routes.rb file. When I try to start the rails server after adding that, i receive the error: /Users/TheBabadook/Desktop/ribbit1/config/routes.rb:9:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `root' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a root path in your routes file:

```
root 'controller_name#action_name' #Make sure to use the actual controller and action names responsible for serving the homepage.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a root to your `config/routes.rb` file as described in [Guidelines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root)

You can use it like this (in rails 4 / 5):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

or there is also the verbose method (in rails 3): `root to: welcome#index`

Comment: When I add 'root 'welcome#index' to my routes.rb file is receive this error message:      /Users/TheBabadook/Desktop/ribbit1/config/routes.rb:9:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `root' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
 from

Comment: Did you include the root line inside the `Rails.application.routes.draw` block ?